# How to remove this error while passing command through terminal?

Tags: laravel

PS W:\laravel_xampp\htdocs\blog> php artisan migrate

Migration table created successfully.

In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Spec
  ified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: al
  ter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

In Connection.php line 458:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Spec
  ified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the Migrations guide to fix this all you have to do is edit your **AppServiceProvider.php** file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```